# Remove duplicate rows keeping the ones that appear first and all columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

An example df:

```
a = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c")
b = c(1,4,3,2,5)
df = cbind.data.frame(a,b)
```

How do I remove duplicate rows searched only by column "a" & keeping the ones that appear first. I want to keep the other columns for corresponding rows. Desired output:

```
a1 = c("c","b","a")
b1 = c(5,4,1)
df1 = cbind.data.frame(a1,b1)
```

I want to use the code within a dplyr pipe. For example,

```
df2 = df %>% arrange(desc(b)) %>% filter(b >= 1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
df[!duplicated(a), ]

#   a b
# 1 a 1
# 2 b 4
# 5 c 5
```

To use with pipe, create a function,

```
uniqueValues <- function(df, columnName){
    df[!duplicated(df[columnName]), ]
}

> df %>% arrange(desc(b)) %>% filter(b >= 1) %>% uniqueValues('a')
# a b
# 1 c 5
# 2 b 4
# 5 a 1
```

Comment: Cannot use this with a dplyr pipe!

Comment: Added example to be used with pipe.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution I found is to use: `group_by(a) %>% summarise(b=head(b,1))`